# Composer private repository in LAN

Tags: git, version-control, repository, composer-php

Is there any way to use git repository as composer VCS in LAN? I tried

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "//server/ServerParallax/gitServer/repo"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "namespace/repo" : "dev-master"
},
```

I get this error:
No valid `composer.json` was found in any branch or tag of   `//server/ServerParallax/gitServer/repo`, could not load a package from it.

When I change url to `"C:/Users/Welsiton/Desktop/repo"` to work locally work fine. But in LAN don't work.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes composer doesn't support unc paths. You will need to map the share to a drive letter and use that instead.